# Do numbers, in random module, have the same chance to appear or not to appear?

Tags: python, random

i want to  build a program in Python designed for generating hazard numbers in lotto. For example from 1 to 45 , i want that every number between  1 and 45 ( 1 and 45 included) have the same chance to appear or not, **like in real life**.
What is ( or what are) the appropriate random that can do that or closer to do that (approximation).
EXEMPLE
value= random.randint(1,46)
Does all the numbers between 1 and 45 have the same chance to appear or to not appear like in reel world ?
Does chance in computer world is like chance in reel world, if no , how to make it closer?
It is not about duplication.
Thank you for helping

Comment: `from random import randint` then `randint(1, 45)`

Comment: Yes, all numbers should have the same chance. If that is not so, that would be a serious bug in the underlying random number generator. If you want to test it, simply repeatedly generate random numbers and count the occurrence of each. After a few million numbers, you should not be able to see statistically significant differences.

Answer (score 2):

You want to sample *k* numbers, without replacement, from a discrete uniform distribution on the interval [1, 45].

Let's say you want to pick 6 numbers. Then write

```
import random

winners = random.sample(range(1, 46), k=6)
```

Then `winners` will be a list of six randomly chosen numbers.

Explanation:

- `range(1, 45)` represents the interval [1, 45). In other words, it wouldn't include 45. So the second argument is 46.
- `sample` chooses *k* numbers from that range of 45 **without replacement**. In other words, just like in the typical lottery, no number will be chosen twice — which you can't count on with other `random` module functions.
- The distribution will be uniform by default; each number is equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation and for your exemple